# How do I return a binding from an ActiveRecord record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have some code stored in a string and I want to run it in the context of a specific record.

I want to do something like this:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has the attributes name and age
end

a_dog = Dog.first

some_code = "puts name"

eval some_code, a_dog.get_binding
```

That would print the first dogs' name. I know the `get_binding` method isn't right but I think the name demonstrates what I want to do.

Also, I know I *shouldn't* do this, I just want to know if there's a way I can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [instance_eval](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_eval) method which evaluates a code string within the context of the receiver.

```
a_dog = Dog.first
a_dog.instance_eval('puts name')
snuppy
 => nil
```

Comment: Cool. I knew there would be a simple way of doing it. Thanks. Although I would never call my dog "Snuppy."

Comment: Although now I looked Snuppy up, that's a cool reference, and I probably would!